# SBT built error : [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:

Tags: apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to execute a spark program using sbt built but getting the below errors.

---

```
'[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-app;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-core;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: asm#asm;3.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#hadoop-core_2.10;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client_2.11;2.2.0: not found
[error] download failed: org.apache.avro#avro;1.7.7!avro.jar
[error] download failed: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.4!commons-codec.jar
```

---

attaching code as well as sbt built. I have set the folder structure correctly though.

helloSpark.scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConetxt
import org.apache.spark.SparkConetxt._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object HelloSpark {
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Hello Spark")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val rddFile = sc.textFile("data.txt").filter(line => line.contains("spark")).count()
    println("lines with spark: %s".format(rddFile))

  }

}
```

simple.sbt:

```
name := "Hello Spark"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "hadoop-core" % "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client_2.11" % "2.2.0"
```

Comment: Try with only these two dependencies `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2"` and `"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.2.0"`, because  your second one doesn't seems to exists and `hadoop-client` doesn't depend on the scala version

Comment: And you have a typo in your imports in helloSpark.scala, it's `SparkContext`.

Comment: Thanks Luca, I corrected the typo and used the above library dependencies but still getting below error: [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-app;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-core;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient;2.2.0: not found